# Instantiate programmatically SVG element with a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg, angular-material

I would use tooltip module in angular project based on SVG files.

I have to generate tooltips dynamically.

I should use JS to add `matTooltip` attribute

Here's what I have done:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const cir1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  cir1.setAttribute("cx", "80");
  cir1.setAttribute("cy", "50");
  cir1.setAttribute("r", "30");
  cir1.setAttribute("fill", "green");
  let svg = document.getElementById('svg');
  cir1.setAttribute('matTooltip', 'N8688');
  svg.appendChild(cir1)
  }
```

I get no tooltip shown when hover.

But when I apply `matTooltip` attribute directly to SVG it's working.

**Update**

I should add directive dynamically but I don't find a way to.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-starter-8gp9pp?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with SVG elements in particular. An Angular directive is not merely an attribute. You can't create / add a directive dynamically by setting the attribute on a DOM element.

Comment: Thanks , that's clear. so is there a way to apply a directive from component ?

Comment: AFAIK just the usual way - use the directive as part of the component template. e.g. `<path [matTooltip]="pathTooltip" ...>` and `this.pathTooltip = 'N8688';`

Comment: My element should be generated automatically